# Runtime Error 1004: Showing Unable to get the PivotTables property of the Worksheet class

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Worksheets("input").PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotCache.Refresh
End Sub
```

I'm trying to autorefresh a excel file. This code has worked for different file. sheet name and pivot table name are correctly put

Comment: I think the error message is clear enough. You do not have a pivot table with the name `PivotTable2` on that worksheet